# Why it went through the if

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can someone try to explain to me why the "If" statement allowed it to went through but clearly you can see the property of my object is saying "EXISTING" even it say in if that it only allow "NEW".

[image]

```
 var newChannalChecker = false;
      singleMassiveGroup.forEach(singleGrop => {
        if (!newChannalChecker && singleGrop.length) {
          singleGrop.forEach(element => {
            if (element["currentItemStatus"] === "NEW") {
              newChannalChecker = true;
            }
          });
        }
      });
```

I am not sure if this would be help but I tried putting some logs with it to check whats going on

```
 var newChannalChecker = false;
      singleMassiveGroup.forEach(singleGroup => {
        if (!newChannalChecker && singleGroup.length) {
          // singleGrop.filter(e => e.CurrentItemStatus === "NEW").map(e)
          singleGroup.forEach(element1 => {
            console.log("CurrentItemStatus: ", element1.CurrentItemStatus);
            if (element1.CurrentItemStatus === "NEW") {
              console.log(
                "Entered CurrentItemStatus: ",
                element1.CurrentItemStatus
              );
              newChannalChecker = true;
            }
          });
        }
      });
```

> App.js:402 CurrentItemStatus:  EXISTING

The weird thing is it says the the Value says "EXISTING" but its still went inside the if

[image]

[image]

I tried hovering to the property it says "Element1 is not defined"

One more thing I noticed the console.log inside my "If" statement didn't print anything but it still change the newChannalChecker to True

Comment: just javascript things... that's a new one.

Comment: I think we need more context. It's clearly impossible that that particular object passed that `if` check. But it's inside a loop, inside another loop, and if *any* of the objects checked in that double-loop have the `currentItemStatus` property set to `"NEW"` then `newChannalChecker` will end up being `true`. So I'm not sure on what makes you confident that anything strange is going on. Knowing the rest of your data would be helpful.

Comment: I hypothesize you might be seeing an element values popup for a previously iterated element. Add a console log within the if?

Comment: sometimes devtools is not always in sync with the actual data, or its showing updated data. [i had a "strange" behavior recently](https://twitter.com/sag1v/status/1042755808587595776) but then figured out its devtools showing me different data then i expected

Comment: just in case: are you sure position of execution is valid? sometimes sourcemap make dev tools highlighting wrong line as current one(and actual line is 1-2-3 positions above highlighted one)

Comment: I added more information to help out solving this. Let me know if you want me try anything

Comment: OK, what you're seeing is too strange. I'd agree with @skyboyer - it appears as if the debugger is not correctly synced with the source. In another comment you said that the `console.log` inside the `if` didn't execute, so I would guess that means that the body of the `if` wasn't executed. To be extra sure, you can assign the value of `element1.CurrentItemStatus === "NEW"` to a variable before the `if`, then print it, then do `if (resultFromComparison)`. If it says that you shouldn't be going in the `if` and you don't get the inner log, then it's the debugger problem.

Comment: I tried checking the status at the end and if I just based on the results of the console the console.log("Checker", newChannalChecker); is printing false(Which is what I want). Looks like( and Hopefully) its just a problem with the debugger. Its my first time to experience this kind of problem with the debugger.

Answer (score -1):

I have seen some similar problems with chrome devtools,

do one thing

`console.log(element["currentItemStatus"]` inside the if block,

it should give you the correct value. That will not be`NEW` only

Comment: not necessarily true. `console.log` sometimes updating the log after its being logged.

Comment: does it pring `entered` part ?

Comment: I tried this console.log("CurrentItemStatus: ", element1.CurrentItemStatus); and the console retuend "CurrentItemStatus:  EXISTING"

Comment: did the console log inside if printed the same thing ?

Comment: `console.log(
                "Entered CurrentItemStatus: ",
                element1.CurrentItemStatus
              );`

Comment: I tried it but it didnt print anything in the console but when I was debugging it, it sets the newChannalChecker to true

Comment: if console.log inside `if` is not executed that means its behaving correctly

Comment: raise a bug for chrome dev tools

Answer (score -1):

I don't see any problem there. While you hover over the debug element, the value of `element["currentItemStatus"]` to be `"EXISTING"` set from somewhere else.

The debugger tool is showing the value of that. Debugger tool shows you the latest updated value of the variable.

This simple test will satisfy you how debugger tool works.

```js
let abc = 1;
abc = 5;
debugger;
```

Hover over `abc` in `let abc`, then you will see it's value to be 5 not 1.

Here's another test using if condition:

```js
let nn = 1;
if(nn===1) { // hover here in nn, you'll see 'Nope!', but not 1
console.log('test passed'); // in fact, the condition is matched nn === 1
}
nn = 'Nope!';
debugger;
```

**Hint: Open developer tool and then run the above code snippet.**

Comment: I dont have concurrent code running thats the problem

Comment: OP is saying there is no other thread that runs code. How would the element be changed by some *other* code, when the only code that should be executed at the time is in and around that `if`?

Comment: You mentioned in your previous comment that somewhere in my code I am setting the CurrentItemStatus, but the thing about that is this is the only code runnning at the moment, I was planning to call an API after this property has been verified

Comment: @vlaz it's not possible. without the change, debugger tool will not show `EXISTING`. There's no AI :P

Comment: It print "test passed"

Comment: Yes, that's what expected.